# AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'lineEdit_3'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Link to my full code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0tdnm2yd8038fwh/additem.py?dl=0

This is the error I get:

```
  File "C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/additem.py", line 187, in <module>
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
  File "C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/additem.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.setupUi(self)
  File "C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/additem.py", line 66, in setupUi
    self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept())
  File "C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/additem.py", line 169, in accept
    brandName = self.lineEdit_3.text()
AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'lineEdit_3'
```

Every goes well before I add:

```
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept())
```

Calling this method:

```
def accept(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('inventory.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    unix = time.time()
    dateUpdated = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    company = self.lineEdit_2.text()
    brandName = self.lineEdit_3.text()
    genericName = self.lineEdit_4.text()
    purchasePrice = self.lineEdit_5.text()
    category = self.lineEdit_6.text()
    sellingPrice = purchasePrice * sellingFactor
    quantity = self.lineEdit_7.text()
    #dosageForm = self.lineEdit_9.text()
    expiryDate = self.lineEdit_10.text()

    c.execute(
        "INSERT INTO inventory(dateUpdated, company, brandName, genericName, category, purchasePrice, sellingPrice, quantity, expiryDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        (dateUpdated, company, brandName, genericName, category, purchasePrice, sellingPrice, quantity, expiryDate))
    conn.commit()
```

This is the rest of the code:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QDialog()

ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(window)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Without seeing `C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/additem.py` it's hard to guess. But likely there is no such attribute.

Comment: @ThomasKilian It has already been answered by eyllanesc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect a signal to a slot you must pass it on behalf of the slot, the syntax is as follows

```
sender.signal.connect(receiver.slot)
```

In your case you must change:

```
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept())
```

to:

```
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
```

*Note*: When you pass the PyQt slot name you can invoke it, but if you pass the evaluated function it is impossible for it to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot @eyllanesc!